# How do you print nicely in LEDA

Tags: visual-studio

How do you print 'nicely' in LEDA?
I am looking for the equivalent to
 fixed
 setprecision(3)

Comment: what the hell is "LEDA"?

Comment: This? i think: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leda_(programming_language)

Comment: Or this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Efficient_Data_types_and_Algorithms ?

Answer (score 0):

I have got a little further with this.
There is a difference between precision and output precision.

I can set LEDA's output precision with e.g bigfloat::set_output_precision(4);

but I still do not know what LEDA's equivalent to fixed is.

Also, I do not know what the latest LEDA of todouble is

I have tried mu.todouble() where mu is declared as a bigfloat, but I get a compiler error

Answer (score 0):

A further answer is mu.to_double()